# Computers not using binary?

Tags: windows, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, computer-science

I don't know if this is the right place to ask such question but, ALL computers use binary, when you program the compiler always turn your code into a "01" form. 
But, are there computers that do NOT work on that principle?

If yes, what kind of computers they are? What can they do and how were they created?
If no, why can't such computers be made?

Thanks and I hope this is good information for anyone looking for a similar answer.

Comment: @KenWhite and where is that proceed exactly? What's inside the computer the control the bits? The ram?
Do you possibly have any links pointing to additional information for beginners?

Comment: @KenWhite: This is incorrect in multiple ways.  (1) Current flows in both states: 1 and 0.  (2) Modern computers use voltage, not current.  (3) Not "any" voltage or current is on, the voltage has to be above a threshold. (4) Analog computers exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but they are esoteric.  Modern computers are digital, use base two, are electronic, and use classical systems largely due to the success of integrated digital logic circuits, but it was a long road and other types of computers have been invented along the way.

### Digital computers in other bases

A handful of computers were made based on ternary (base 3) logic.  Some of these used bipolar voltages to represent values in balanced ternary.  The general consensus is that if you are going to use digital circuitry, binary is the best option, so this is mostly a historical curiosity.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer

### Analog and mechanical computers

Analog computers use continuous voltages to represent values.  Mechanical computers use the positions of physical parts, such as gear shafts, to represent values.  There is some renewed interest in analog computers for problems such as image analysis, where researchers suspect that the benefits of performance outweigh the disadvantages of accumulated error.  Whether analog computers see a resurgence is unknown.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer

### Quantum computers

Quantum computers represent values using superpositions of quantum states.  Creating a large quantum computer is an open problem, and a number of algorithms have already been written for quantum computers which would outperform classical implementations.  For example, Shor's algorithm.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing

Comment: Now that's a fully completed answer, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I heard, tho, that Quantum computers are only faster than binary computers in "certain" operations but not all. Like, if someone want to surf the web or write some document, QCs might be slower. Is that right, in your opinion?

Comment: Rather than answer your question—if quantum computers arrive, they will come attached to classical computers, just like GPUs come attached to CPUs.  If you browse the web, your CPU will be controlling things but your GPU may be decoding and compositing video.  Right now, browsing the web is faster on a classical computer, because it's impossible on a quantum computer.  In theory, quantum computers are never asymptotically slower than classical computers, because you could make a classical computer by removing features from a quantum computer. For more understanding, search "complexity theory".

Comment: I believe most traditional quantum computers use binary.  They use superpositions, of course, but the states that are being superposed (the qubits) represent binary values, the arithmetic parts of Shor's algorithm is performed in binary, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's quite correct.  However, it's sufficiently different from binary logic—you can't just do arbitrary binary logic on the qubits, for example, while still retaining superposition.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking all computers are based on a voltage of

```
0 = no voltage
1 = yes voltage
```

However, there are new "Quantum computers" that are far from complete that do not use a 0-1, instead they use quantum bits.

Here is more information on the topic:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing

Comment: Could you explain to me, please, in details what exactly does "based on voltage" means?

Comment: Your computer has these "logic states" of electricity when the computer recognizes a 1 binary digit, the computer is receiving 5 volts, when it is receiving 0 volts (technically under ~0.7 volts) it is processed as a 0 logic state.

Comment: I see. So explain to me for example, if I write a  random code (in any language) and execute it, what happens "exactly" INSIDE the computer?

Comment: First, the computer complies it to machine language [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) which is essentially a single instruction. These instructions are then executed.

Comment: Thanks! The image is starting to get clearer now, thanks again. :)